# Error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 while working with contours using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

When  I run this code:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('screenshoot10.jpg')
cv2.imshow('input image', image)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
cv2.imshow('canny edges', edged)

_, contours = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.imshow('canny edges after contouring', edged)

print(contours)
print('Numbers of contours found=', len(contours))

cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('contours', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting this error:

> OpenCV(4.1.1)
> C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function
> 'cv::drawContours'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of the two print statements? how many contours did you find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) for findContours, the method returns (contours, hierarchy), so I think the code should be:

```py
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

instead of

```py
_, contours = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Comment: When calling an error, version - 4.1.1, how does it work?

Comment: My bad, no need to assume the version, as it is properly stated in the question. However, I think it does not change the answer, as I have read the documentation for 4.1.1 and it returns a tuple (countours, hierarchy).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the OpenCV version, `cv2.findContours()` has varying return signatures. In `v3.4.X`, three items are returned.

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

In `v2.X` and `v4.1.X`, two items are returned.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])
```

You can easily obtain the contours regardless of the version like this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    ...
```

Since the last two values are always the same, we can further condense it into a single line using `[-2:]` to extract the contours from the tuple returned by `cv2.findContours()`

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
```

Comment: I was using v4.5.3 and ```cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]``` solved the issue. I was using ```cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]```

Answer (score 3):

Because this question shows up on top when looking for `Error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 while working with contours using OpenCV`, I want to point out another possible reason as to why one can get this error:

I was using the `BoxPoints` function after doing `minAreaRect` to get a rotated rectangle around a contour. I hadn't done `np.int0` to its output (to convert the returned array to integer values) before passing it to drawContours. This fixed it:

```py
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) 
box = np.int0(box) # convert to integer values
cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

Comment: `np.int0` is a deprecated alias for `np.intp`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)

`box = np.intp(box) # convert to integer values`

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions provided here are either fixed for a particular version or they do not store all the values returned from `cv2.findContours()`. You can store all the values returned from every tuple of the function independent of the version of `cv2`.

The following snippet will work irrespective of the OpenCV version installed in your system/environment and will also store all the tuples in individual variables.

First, get the version of OpenCV installed (we don't want the entire version just the major number ***either 3 or 4***) :

```
import cv2
version = cv2.__version__[0]
```

Based on the version either of the following two statements will be executed and the corresponding variables will be populated:

```
if version == '4':
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

elif version == '3':
    img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

The contours returned from the function in either scenarios will be stored in `contours`.

> ***Note:*** the above snippet is written assuming either version 3 or 4 of OpenCV is installed. For older versions, please refer to the documentation or update to the latest.

If you are using OpenCV version 4, and wondering what the first variable returned by `cv2.findContours()` of version 3 is; its just the same as the input image (in this case `binary_image`).

Comment: `img` is possibly unbound, for a complete implementation we should generate the `img` for the `version == '4'`

Comment: Under version `4`, the no image is returned. How do you propose to generate one?

Comment: I have no idea why `img` is returned and how it's used, but if it have no use for us, I'd ignore it as a whole. If it's useful, then for sure there would be an explanation of what is `img` in the docs, so we could generate it ourselves for the 4th version

Comment: Exactly, this code is written if the returned variables need to be processed further in the code. If not needed can be ignored

Comment: I just wanted to say that you as a experienced SO user could greatly increase the value of your answer (thus possibly helping others) by adding the code that generates the `img` for the 4th version, so there would be no differences for users of different versions

Comment: @0dminnimda In version `3` of OpenCV, `img` is the same as the input image `binary_image`. Hence in version `4` `img` can be assumed to be the same. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't have version 3 and had to test it out before confirming